# remove all lines from file except one

Tags: linux, awk, sed, scripting

I have the following file:

```
cat file.txt
User-agent: *
Disallow: /a-path*
Disallow: /000111/
Disallow: /*/my-path

User-agent: megaindex
Disallow: /

User-agent: DigitalPebble
Disallow: /

User-agent: EISSAB
Disallow: /

User-agent: archive.org_bot
Disallow: /

User-agent: dotbot
Disallow: /
```

I need to keep only the directive for `User-agent:*` block together with the Disallow values, and remove all the lines beneath.

So in this case, only the following should remain:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /a-path*
Disallow: /000111/
Disallow: /*/my-path
```

And the following to be removed:

```
User-agent: megaindex
Disallow: /

User-agent: DigitalPebble
Disallow: /

User-agent: EISSAB
Disallow: /

User-agent: archive.org_bot
Disallow: /

User-agent: dotbot
Disallow: /
```

Comment: Is the one you want to keep always the first one?

Comment: Your description of the problem and your actual presented example are inconsistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using GNU awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="\n\n"} $1=="User-agent:" && $2 == "*"' file
```

The script relies on multiline record in order to parse every block of text at once.

The set of lines is printed only if `User-agent: *` is the first part of the text block.

Answer (score 0):

Oliv answer works.
Also, I managed to make it work using the

```
sed '/User\-agent\:\ .../,$d' < file.txt > newfile.txt
```

Basically, sed is using regex and if it finds `User:agent: some multiple characters` (using "..."), it will remove everything below.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use `grep`:

```
egrep 'User-agent:[[:space:]]*\*' file.txt
```